# Can't move any objects in my scene

Tags: interface, geometry

I was modeling an object thanks to three cubes and then I made a flower with its respective "accessories", the thing is that maybe I pressed something that I don't know, because now all my objects on the scene have an orange outline and I can't move them.

If I press <kbd>A</kbd> two times I'm able to move everything on the layer.

Also, if I unselect the objects, then I can't move anything with right click.

[image]

Comment: Could you upload the [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Could imagine you've created a new scene, because the outliner is empty: http://i.stack.imgur.com/z62u4.png Try to switch back to the old one.

Comment: Having the same issue, (2.82) cannot move selected objects. My outliner is not empty and reflects that specific items are selected, however they will not move or be resized or acted upon in any way. This happened after I selected and separated a curve object from other grouped curve objects.